# Camel Rest DSL is not recognizing JsonProperty access

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I am using Camel Rest DSL to build my rest service but it seems that , it does not recognize JsonProperty annotation.

I have a propery like:

```
class Test {

    private int id;

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private String text;
}
```

and the rest definition is:

```
<rests xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <rest consumes="application/json" produces="application/json" path="/api/v1">
        <post bindingMode="json" type="Test" uri="/path">
            <route>
                .....
            </route>
        </post>
    </rest>
</rests>
```

When I call it with :

```
{
    "id":2,
    "text":"asd"
}
```

Text field is also getting initialized.

What am I missing?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in Jackson's @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY).
For more information please refer to: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/935

There are two workarounds mentioned in bug report:

- "The only thing that helps is to create a setter and annotate it with @JsonIgnore"
- "@JsonIgnoreProperties(value="some_field", allowGetters = true, allowSetters = false)"